# Show subset of $\ell^2$ is compact

Tags: functional-analysis

How does one go about showing if the following subsets of $\ell^2$ are compact or not:

$$\{a\in \ell^2 : \|a\|_2=1\}$$

$$\{a\in \ell^2 : |a_k|\leq \frac{1}{k} \forall k\in\mathbb{N}\}$$

I thought that a subset being comapct meant that every sequence $\{x_n\}$ in the subset contains a subsequence that converges to an element in the metric space. But for example the first sequence when $a$ belongs to $\ell^2$ and it's norm is less than one isn't it 'trivial' that the sequence would converge to an element of $\ell^2$? For the second sequence I suppose that $k=0$ which would make the norm tend to infinity so that it's not compact in $\ell^2$?

Comment: "I suppose that $k=0$"? What?

Comment: Try to avoid using $|$ notation with norms. It is not great to look at.

Answer (score 1):

The first one is not compact since it contains the subset $A=\{\mathbf e_n \in \ell^2 : n\in\mathbb N \} $, where
$$\mathbf e_n(k) =\begin{cases} 1 \text{ if } n=k \\ 0 \text{ if } n\neq k \end{cases}$$
That subset $A$ does not have any limit point, because the distance between two (distinct) elements of $A$ is $\sqrt 2$. That is: there existe a $\varepsilon >0$ such that for every $n\in\mathbb N$, $d(x_n, n_{n+1})\geq \varepsilon$, which is the negation of a sequence being Cauchy. So that, any sequence in $A$ cannot be Cauchy, hence cannot converge.

Comment: I think that the second one (let us denote it as $B$) is compact. The idea of the proof is as follows: Given any open cover $\mathcal O$ of $B$, since the sequence $b(n) = \frac 1 n$ is in $B$, we have that there exists an element $U_b\in \mathcal O$ such that $b \in U_b$. Furthermore, there exists a $\delta >0$ such that $B_ \delta (b) \subseteq U_b$, and by the archimedian property, there exists a minimum $K \in \mathbb N $ such that $\frac 1 K < \delta$. Now you only have to take care about the points of the form $\frac 1 k \mathbf e_k$ for $k<K$ to cover the rest of $B$.

Answer (score 0):

As Emmanuel has shown your first set is not compact.

We shall show that the second set, which we shall call $A$, is sequentially compact, thus compact. Let $(x_n)\subset A$. We first note that for every $k\in \mathbb N$ we can find an $x^k\in A$ and a subsequence $(x_{n}^k)\subset (x_n)$ such that $|\pi_ix^k-\pi_ix^k_n|\to 0$ for all $i=1,\dots,k$, where $\pi_i$ is just the projection onto the $i$-th coordinate. Note that superscripts are just used to denote a label. Furthermore we can make this choice inductively, so that for each $j<k\in \mathbb N$ we have $\pi_ix^j=\pi_ix^k$ for all $i=1,\dots,j$, and $(x^k_n)\subset (x^j_n)$. Now let us define $x\in A$ by $\pi_i x=\pi_i x^i$ for all $i\in \mathbb N$. We further define a subsequence $(x_{n_j})\subset (x_n)$ by setting $x_{n_j}=x_j^j$  for all $j\in\mathbb N$ (this is what is often referred to as a diagonalisation argument).

Finally, we claim that $x_{n_j}\to x$ in $\ell^2$. Fix $\varepsilon>0$. By definition of $A$ there must exist some $N\in \mathbb N$ such that
$$\sum_{k=N}^\infty|\pi_kx_{n_j}-\pi_kx|^2<\varepsilon$$
for all $j\in\mathbb N$.
Furthermore, by our choice of $x_{n_j}$ and $x$ there must exist a $J\in\mathbb N$ so
$$\sum_{i=1}^{N-1}|\pi_ix_{n_j}-\pi_ix|^2<\varepsilon$$for all $j>J$. Putting these two facts together proves the claim.

Comment: Thank you for yoru help. I don't understand why given the definition of A we have $|\pi_i x^k - \pi_i x^k_n|$ and the first sum?